# CSS – positioning image between text and background color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to recreate something, which I myself did by mistake:
https://bgiltphotos.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/img.jpg

It was my very first CSS attempt, and I kept adding selectors in a stopgap fashion. Then I decided to rewrite the file, and did not save the original...

This has an img `position:absolute` and an h1 in the header section, and then comes the article text. What I can't reproduce is the positioning of the image for the first three lines of the text: it's between the text and the background color (I then reversed the text color just for these three lines). Whatever I tried now, I either have the image covering both text and background color, or else the background color covering the image from the first line of text.

Here is the current CSS:

```
html { 
    background-color: #5F5F5F;
}

img.shost {   
    position: absolute;    
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
}

div#headertext {
    position: relative;
    top: 5em;
    left: 2.0em;
    width: 60em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

div#articleMain {
    position: relative;
    top: 10em;
    width: 60em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #fdfdf9;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: can you provide css ?

Comment: Create a fiddle reproducing your issue, please.

Comment: Sorry, what's a fiddle?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please do not use tags like [background-color], [positioning], etc. They are ambiguous and exists in nearly all programming languages. So they are redundant and unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it – had to give the background-color property to body and not to article.

Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `img.shost` is your image just add a property `top` and mess around with the variables until you find your desired image position

Heres a sloppy **Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/MaYdbj

just change the `top:-120%;` and you can see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

please try to give the image z-index= -1;

it should work if you give a z-index value to the relative positioned parent

Comment: Thanks, I tried it already, it moves it beneath the background colour of the text block